# Parsing CSV into multiple, separate dictionaries

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am looking for a way through python to take only sections of a CSV and put them into dictionaries.

```
id,name,ipsubnet,mask,protocol,area,type,cost
101,default,10.1.1.0,255.255.255.0,ospf,0.0.0.0,ptp,1
102,servers2,10.1.2.0,255.255.255.0,ospf,0.0.0.0,,
103,server3,10.1.3.0,255.255.255.0,ospf,0.0.0.0,,
104,server4,10.1.4.0,255.255.255.0,ospf,0.0.0.0,,
```

I already have the code to take this whole thing and make it a dictionary and it works just fine. I am trying to for exmaple only grab ID and NAME but ignore the other fields for dictionary 1, then take IPSUBNET, MASK, PROTOCOL into dictionary 2.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Hey there. Please update your post with the dictionary creation code you have in place. It'll improve your chances of getting a response. Here's a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) you'll find useful.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that the `id` will be the key for both dictionaries?

Comment: Its a single dictionary? So, each header is a key and its value is a list of the column?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

I'm making some assumptions about your schema, but I'm guessing you want it to look something like this...

```py
d1 = {
   "101" : {
      "name" : "default"
   },
   "102" : {
      "name" : "servers2"
   }
   # etc...
}

d2 = {
   "101" : {
      "ipsubnet" : 10.1.1.0,
      "mask" : 255.255.255.0,
      # etc...
   }
   "102" : {
      # etc...
   }
}
```

If that's the case, then you can do something like this:

```py
# Use the `csv` library to pull in everything
import csv

data_rows = []

with open("your_csv_file.csv", newline="") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:
        data_rows.append(row)

# Now you have everything in your data_rows variable
# Parse it out however you want

d1 = {}
d2 = {}

# Use data_rows[1:] to start at the first row of data and not the column headers
for row in data_rows[1:]:
    # Note the use of row[0] to grab the IP address as the index
    d1[row[0]] = {
        "name" : row[1]
    }

    # Do the same thing for d2, and grab the other variables you want
    d2[row[0]] = {
        "ipsubnet" : row[2],
        "mask" : row[3],
        # etc...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data_set = pd.read_csv("csv.file")

dic1 = {}
dic2 = {}
count = 0

for id, name in data_set[['id', 'name']].values:
    dic = {'id':id, 'name':name}
    dic1[count] = dic
    count = count + 1
    
count = 0

for  ipsubnet , mask, protocol, area ,type , cost in data_set[[ 'ipsubnet', 'mask' ,'protocol'  ,'area' ,'type' , 'cost']].values:
    dic = {'ipsubnet':ipsubnet, 'mask':mask ,'protocol':protocol  ,'area':area ,'type':type , 'cost':cost}
    dic2[count] = dic
    count = count + 1
```